# DNS records malfunctioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53, elastic-load-balancer

I've some issue in AWS Route53

```
2 EC2 instances in the same region. 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -hosted: domain.tld & www.domain.tld
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -hosted: abc.dpmain.tld & pqr.domain.tld

2 load-balancers: 
elb-1.aws.com - instances: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
elb-2.aws.com - instances: yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy

Route53 records: 
record| name           | value
-----------------------------------------
    A | domain.tld     | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
CNAME | abc.domain.tld | elb-2.aws.com
CNAME | pqr.domain.tld | elb-2.aws.com
CNAME | www.domain.tld | elb-1.aws.com
```

[*.].domain.tld are accessible but 'domain.tld' is not, 
what to do now to make 'domain.tld' accessible?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the TLD you need to use an ALIAS record.

[Routing Traffic to an ELB Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)

While ordinary Amazon Route 53 resource record sets are standard DNS resource record sets, alias resource record sets provide an Amazon Route 53–specific extension to DNS functionality. Instead of an IP address or a domain name, an alias resource record set contains a pointer to a CloudFront distribution, an Elastic Beanstalk environment, an ELB Classic, Application, or Network Load Balancer, an Amazon S3 bucket that is configured as a static website, or another Amazon Route 53 resource record set in the same hosted zone. When Amazon Route 53 receives a DNS query that matches the name and type in an alias resource record set, Amazon Route 53 follows the pointer and responds with the applicable value.

Comment: I am not understanding. now how can I fix this?

Comment: In Route 53, configure your apex (domain.tld) to be an A record, select ALIAS and enter or select the load balancers dns name.